# Django: Save foreign key value in a forms raise an error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have to tables correlated with a foreign key.

Demographics tables with primary key patient_id (required) and diagnosis having foreign key patient. I've created two forms. I save the fields on first form and then the patient field is autocompleted in diagnosis form.

The problem, is when I'm trying to save the fields' values on diagnosis form, I get an error on the first form which says 'This field is required' even this field's value was stored a minute ago.

**Edited: This is my solution**

**input.html (template)**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Demographics</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Diagnosis</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">A_b_sickle</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="demographics">
                <p>{%crispy frm%}</p>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="2">
                <!-- form controls to be continued here -->
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="diagnosis">
                {%crispy frm_d%}
                <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="3">
                <!-- form controls to be continued here -->
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="a_b_s">
                {%crispy frm_a_b_s%}
                <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 3.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--<input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit">-->
</form>
```

My **view.py** contains:

```
def input(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
    my_demographics = DemographicForm(request.POST, prefix="demo")
    my_diagnosis = DiagnosisForm(request.POST, prefix='diag')
    my_a_b_sickle= A_b_sickle_thalForm(request.POST,prefix='a_b_s')

    if my_demographics.is_valid() and my_diagnosis.is_valid() and my_a_b_sickle.is_valid:
        my_demographics_object = my_demographics.save()
        my_diagnosis_object = my_diagnosis.save(commit=False)
        my_diagnosis_object.patient = my_demographics_object
        my_diagnosis_object.save()

        my_a_b_sickle_object = my_a_b_sickle.save(commit=False)
        my_a_b_sickle_object.patient = my_demographics_object

        my_a_b_sickle_object.save()

    else:
    my_demographics = DemographicForm(prefix='demo')
    my_diagnosis = DiagnosisForm(prefix='diag')
    my_a_b_sickle= A_b_sickle_thalForm(prefix='a_b_s')

return render_to_response('input.html', {'frm':my_demographics, 'frm_d': my_diagnosis, 'frm_a_b_s': my_a_b_sickle}, context)
```

**models.py**

```
class demographic(models.Model):
    national_health_care_pat_id = models.IntegerField('National Health Care patient id', null=True,blank=True)
    patient_hospital_file_number = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    patient_id = models.IntegerField(unique= True ,primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient_id)

class diagnosis(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(demographic)
    age_of_diagnosis = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient_id)
```

**forms.py**

```
class DemographicForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DemographicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper=FormHelper(self)
        self.fields['date_of_birth'].widget = widgets.AdminDateWidget()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'national_health_care_pat_id',
            'patient_hospital_file_number',
            'patient_id',

            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', "Save changes"),
                Submit('cancel', "Cancel")
            ),

        )
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True

    class Meta:
        model = demographic
        exclude = []

class DiagnosisForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DiagnosisForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper=FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'patient',
            'age_of_diagnosis',

            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', "Save changes"),
               Submit('cancel',"Cancel")
            ),
        )
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True

    class Meta:
        model = diagnosis
        exclude = []
```

Do you have any idea what the problem might be? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please add your model and form classes to your code example?

Comment: @Brando Yes, of course! I added them.

Comment: you are not passing data into the `DiagnosisForm` , only into `DemographicForm`

Comment: @Anentropic Can you be more specific please? What do I do wrong?

Comment: maybe post the end of the traceback you're getting. also you probably want to change `elif my_diagnosis.is_valid():` to `if my_diagnosis.is_valid():` since you need to execute the code in the lines above too before saving a diagnosis

Comment: @Anentropic Yes, I also tried `if` instead of `elif`

Comment: @zinon You should really start your class names in Python with capital letters to differentiate them from instance variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the actual `demographic` object instead of just the ID for your `DiagnosisForm`. Django expects `ForeignKey` fields to point to an instance of the object they represent. You'll also need to exclude the `patient` field from your DiagnosisForm. This will prevent Django from trying to validate the field.

```
# forms.py

class DiagnosisForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        . . .

    class Meta:
        model = diagnosis
        exclude = ['patient']


# views.py

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from your_app.models import Patient

def input(request):
    patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, id=5)
    my_demographics = DemographicForm(request.POST or None)
    my_diagnosis = DiagnosisForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method =='POST':
        if my_demographics.is_valid() and my_diagnosis.is_valid():
            demographic = my_demographics.save()
            my_diagnosis.save(commit=False)
            my_diagnosis.patient = demographic
            my_diagnosis.save()

    return render(request, 'input.html', {'frm':my_demographics, 'frm_d': my_diagnosis})
```

Comment: Can you give me a simple example please?

Comment: I've added an example for you.

Comment: I don't have a model Patient. patient is only a field in Diagnosis model. I need to get the patient number added to Demographics form (after I push the submit button for this form) and put it in Diagnosis form and then complete the Diagnosis form and save it. That's the reason I pass the my_demographics_object.patient_id value.

Comment: The `my_diagnosis = DiagnosisForm(initial={'patient': '5'})` is just to give an initial value before get the proper one.

Comment: So, I fill in the demographics form, save and then get from this form the patient_id field value and give it as value to patient field in diagnosis form.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I didn't see that patient was actually a ForeignKey to the Demographic model. I'll adjust accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I've adjusted the form classes and view.

Comment: OK, I'll try it. My issue is that I have DON'T save values in TWO forms simultaneously. Firstly, I save Demographics form and then Diagnosis. So my problem is that `if my_demographics.is_valid() and my_diagnosis.is_valid():` won't work, if I save forms independently...

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question and posted my solution. Finally, I use only one `form` tag and used tabs inside the form. So, your solution was suitable for me!